# how to insert more than 5 columns in odbc connection in impala database using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, impala

i am trying to insert below code for five columns:

```cs
List<string> ReadFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Data.txt").ToList();

var cmdText = "INSERT INTO TEST Values (@name, @panno,@city,@Pin,@mobilenumber)";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, Conn);
Conn.Open();

foreach(var col in Readfile)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]; 
    cmd.Parameters["@panno"].Value = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]; 
    cmd.Parameters["@city"].Value = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2]; 
    cmd.Parameters["@Pin"].Value = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[3]; 
    cmd.Parameters["@mobilenumber"].Value = ReadFile[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[4];
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    i++;

}
  Conn.Close();
```

I want above code more efficient and fast for more than 50 column and more than 1Million rows insert at a time in impala table, using odbc connection.

Comment: are you using lcoudera impala ODBC? If yes, i dont see any problems. What is your current speed? You can chunk if needed but for 1Million row, it should be fast.

Comment: The 1 million rows are not a problem. The `foreach` does that for you. You don't need to type that 1 million times, right? `ReadFile` is a bad name. You don't need `readFile[i]`, since you have `col`. `i` is not declared. Also, you should probably not split it each time, but split it once and then reuse it. If you're concerned about 1M database inserts, you can probably chain them all together and use one insert only. Or insert 100 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets much simpler if you consider some easy stuff:

1. Best practice: use `using` for your connection to ensure it doesn't leak.
2. Better naming: `ReadFile` is not good. `lines` is better, maybe `csvLines` is even better. Use lower case for local variables.
3. Don't repeat yourself (DRY): Don't split so often. Split once and reuse the result.
4. `ReadFile[i]` is identical to `col`. Use `col`instead.
5. Better naming: `col` is not a good name, because I assume it means *column*, but it isn't a column, it's a line. This becomes more obvious with change 2.

I think all the above confused yourself.

After that, your code looks like this:

```cs
List<string> csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Data.txt").ToList();

var cmdText = "INSERT INTO TEST Values (@name, @panno,@city,@Pin,@mobilenumber)";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, conn);
using (conn.Open()) // or similar, depending on your database
{  

    foreach(var line in csvLines)
    {
        var columns = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = columns[0]; 
        cmd.Parameters["@panno"].Value = columns[1]; 
        cmd.Parameters["@city"].Value = columns[2]; 
        cmd.Parameters["@Pin"].Value = columns[3]; 
        cmd.Parameters["@mobilenumber"].Value = columns[4]; 
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

} // connection will be closed here
```

Now, what you can do next?

1. You can define all the column names somewhere in a list

```cs
List<string> columnNames = new List<string>{"name", "panno", "city", "Pin", "mobilenumber"};
```

2. Reduce repetition again: you can now loop over the column names and add all parameters in a loop:

```cs
int columnIndex = 0;
foreach (var columneName in columnNames)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@"+columnName] = columns[columnIndex];
}
```

3. Instead of inserting one row at a time, group them in larger quantities, e.g. 100 inserts.